# Haversine formula in php

Tags: php

i am using this code but getting error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function RADIANS() in C:\xampp\htdocs\location.php on line 11

```
    <?php
 // Get lat and long by address         
    $address = $dlocation; // Google HQ
    $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',"India+Meerut+Anandpuri");
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?                   
    address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
    $output= json_decode($geocode);
    $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;


    $location=6371 * ACOS(SIN(RADIANS( $latitude )) * SIN(RADIANS('28.9632936')) +           
    COS(RADIANS( $lat1 )) * COS(RADIANS('28.9632936')) * COS(RADIANS('77.7410846') -    
    RADIANS( $longitude )));

    echo $latitude;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $longitude;
    echo "<br>distance";
    echo $location;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the function deg2rad() not RADIANS(). Try this instead:

```
$location=6371 * ACOS(SIN(deg2rad( $latitude )) * SIN(deg2rad('28.9632936')) +           
    COS(deg2rad( $lat1 )) * COS(deg2rad('28.9632936')) * COS(deg2rad('77.7410846') -    
    deg2rad( $longitude )));
```

This is what your full script should look like (just tested and it worked fine):

```
  <?php

 // Get lat and long by address         
    $address = $dlocation; // Google HQ
    $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',"India+Meerut+Anandpuri");
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
    $output= json_decode($geocode);
    $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    $location=6371 * acos(sin(deg2rad( $latitude )) * sin(deg2rad('28.9632936')) + cos(deg2rad( $latitude )) * cos(deg2rad('28.9632936')) * cos(deg2rad('77.7410846') - deg2rad( $longitude )));

    echo $latitude;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $longitude;
    echo "<br>distance";
    echo $location;
    ?>
```

Comment: again same error comes when using deg2rad instead RADIANS()

Comment: @user3610919 it can't possibly be the same error if you replaced all RADIANS function calls with deg2rad. At the very least the error should have changed to: Fatal error: Call to undefined function deg2rad() in C:\xampp\htdocs\location.php on line 11